# Service vs conversion

Tags: usability-testing, e-commerce, checkout, conversion

I'm trying to optimise my checkout flow and ran into a small issue. Currently we offer our customers a selection of FAQ questions and the answers open in a new tab.

Showing both question and answers in the checkout would clutter and distract way too much. Our target group is mostly 50+ year olds that are generally insecure about buying the items we sell online.

**Is giving them an 'exit' on the checkout page bad for conversion, or is answering their questions and calling a sense of 'trustworthiness' helping the conversion rates?**

We currently have too little users to do a valuable user test, which is why I'm looking for experiences or answers in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're hurting your conversion rate by loading FAQ in a new tab.

This way you are forcing users to go to another tab **breaking their task flow**. Elderly users may not even know that a new tab is opened because they, generally have low computer literacy. That makes the problem even worse.

A much better solution would be to **place the FAQ at the page where the questions arise**. This way you won't break their task flow, and provide needed information.

Don't worry about the clutter. If you open the FAQ in new tab you require much more mental workload than if its displayed in the page itself.

### Trust is important

If users don't trust your site they won't put their personal data. There is a good article by NNgroup about [trust and conversion rate](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/commitment-levels/).

> Sites must meet users' basic trust needs before they demand that
>   visitors enter information or engage with them. The trust pyramid has
>   5 distinct levels of user commitment, each with separate design
>   requirements before users will give a website what it wants from them.

[image]

---

**Small correction**

You said:

> We currently have too little users to do a valuable user test, which
>   is why I'm looking for experiences or answers in this field.

You don't need user base or traffic to make a user test. You need this for A/B tests. To conduct a [user test](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/task-scenarios-usability-testing/) you should recruit target users (age 50+) and then give them tasks to complete while you watch them. Here is a [good resource](http://www.lib.washington.edu/usability/resources/guides/tests) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a user to get a proper test, You can conduct a experiment, such as A/B testing so you would get the answer which one is giving you the best convertions, between giving them an "exit" or "FAQ".

And don't forget for another issues like font size,CTA impression, user flow and so on which will have a bigger impact even looks like small things.

FYI, i've experience with the customers that 50+, i've met several of them, usually they ask their grandchild/son to help them using the website or ask about their opinion to the website they are interested, so the target users could be the millenial which is technology native.

This is a good article:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/young-adults-ux/